# Copy data and past in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the data from the second row to the last row and past on the last row of another workbook. I used the bwlo coding but it is showing an error as:

> Method 'Cells  of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Below is my code

```
Dim myFileNameDir As String
Dim myFileNameDir1 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim iRow1 As Long


myFileNameDir = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book16.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws = Worksheets("Students")


myFileNameDir1 = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book17.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")


Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, ii As Long
Dim r As Long, rlastrow As Long
rlastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
r = rlastrow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To LastRow
                r = r + 1
            ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & r)'change Sheet Name to suit
Next
MsgBox "Macro is Done", vbInformation, "Created By Lancerj017"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function isWorkbookOpen(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name = strName Then
            isWorkbookOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    isWorkbookOpen = False
End Function

Public Sub test()
    Dim myFileNameDir As String
    Dim myFileNameDir1 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rlastrow As Long

    If isWorkbookOpen("Book16.xlsx") Then
        Set ws = Workbooks("Book16.xlsx").Worksheets("Students")
    Else
        myFileNameDir = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book16.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
        Set ws = Worksheets("Students")
    End If

    If isWorkbookOpen("Book17.xlsx") Then
        Set ws1 = Workbooks("Book17.xlsx").Worksheets("Students")
    Else
        myFileNameDir1 = "H:\Shaikh_Gaus\scratch\VBA\Book17.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")
    End If

    rlastrow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & rlastrow + 1)
    MsgBox "Macro is Done", vbInformation, "Created By Lancerj017"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am gettign error as  Runtime Error 9, Subscript out of range

Comment: Make sure you have a "Students" tab in both workbooks you are opening.

Comment: Yes, I have the tabs but not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: When you get the error, press the "Debug" button. Let me know which line of code is producing the error.

Comment: I used another code whcih is running fine but copying only last row. Can you please advise what changes require in below code to copy the entire data.

Comment: I am getting the error on Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students1")

Comment: and if you change "Students1" to "Students"?

Comment: It is a typo error, getting error on  Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")

Comment: I am also getting error that Book16 is already open even after closing the file. When I click 'yes' on question that do you want to reopen the book16, I am getting error as subscription out of range

Comment: Please run the same code, you will also get the same error

Comment: Your errors are coming from opening the files and storing references to the tabs. I can't test with your files. When I used my own files and tab names, it worked without any errors.

Comment: Do you need to save and close the workbook at the end of the code? If you keep running the code with the workbook already open, it will tell you it is already open.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the workbook being open already.